# Error when reading a csv-file to a struct

Tags: c, struct, stack-corruption

I'm in trouble with reading a data from a csv-file and parsing it into a struct. I think its best to show some code.

This is my struct:

```
typedef struct MyStruct{
    char text[150];
    char attr[4][50];
    char check;
    short int num;
} t_mystruct;
```

A sample line in my file could look like this: **This is a long text;brown;green;yellow;silent;X;13;**

Now I want to read that file and add that data to an array:

```
list = malloc(sizeof(t_mystruct) * LIST_SIZE); /* Allocating Memory */

for (i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) /* Adding data to list */
{
    t_mystruct element;

    if (fscanf(fp, "%149[^;];%49[^;];%49[^;];%49[^;];%49[^;];%49[^;];%[^;];%d;", &element.text, &element.attr[0], &element.attr[1], &element.attr[2], &element.attr[3], &element.check, &element.num) != 7)
        break; /* Break ==> Incomplete line/data */

    list[i] = element;  /* Add to list */
}
```

This works, but I face two problems:

1. The "num" value isn't the same value as in my file. I get results from 49 up to around 13000, but they never match my actual input value (13 in my example).
2. The code belongs to a "readFile" function. At the end of that function, I face a **"stack around the variable "element" was corrupted"** error. **Edit:** When debugging, I can continue and the program works as expected.

But I can't see my mistakes.

Comment: Did you try changing `%d;` to `%hd;` as this one's `short int`?

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: `"%149[^;];%49[^;];%49[^;];%49[^;];%49[^;];%c;%hd;%*c"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified *five* format specifiers of

```
%49[^;];
```

but your struct has only four, and you only provide four arguments to match. You are also reading the last value as `int`, when it is `short`.

Comment: Thanks. It often needs a second pair of eyes to find such obvisious typos.